# Query returns all rows when matching a value against 0

Tags: mysql, select

Never come across this before, just cannot understand the reasoning behind it.

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`user`) WHERE `user_email` = 0 AND `user_pass` = 0
```

This shows all rows, even though I would have read the query as 'Show me all records which have the integer 0 in both user_email and user_pass. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put integer 0, so it converts your varchar  fields `user_email` and `user_pass` to int. Actually, if non-null string doesn't have leading number on it, it will be converted to 0. For example,

```
SELECT 'aaaa' = 0; // returns 1 - true
SELECT '1aaa' =0; // 0 -false
SELECT '1aaa' =1 ;// 1 -true
```

Correction. According to [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html), they will be compared as float, not as integers.

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers

Answer (score 1):

I guess your fields user_email and user_pass are varchar fields. So maybe change 0 to `''` (two single quotes)

Comment: Ok I understand where your coming from however it should work without the quotes, providing 1 and 1 instead of 0 and 0 doesnt return all rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have ever seen someone declare a table name using parenthesis before. Have you done this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_email` = 0 AND `user_pass` = 0
```

Comment: Sorry, the content editor stripped some of the markup, that still generates the resulting record set :S.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the parenthesis are required around `user`. Also, try putting quotes around both zeroes, that may be causing the problem.

Comment: They arnt causing the error, the query runs the same without them. I shouldnt really have to put quotes around the data either as it isnt a string, it is an integer. Providing 1 and 1 instead of 0 and 0 returns no rows so it is in particular focussed on 0's. I just want to realise the theory behind why this happens as I have developed for years and never come across this.

Answer (score 0):

Since user_email and user_pass are going to be string types, i think this should do :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = '0' AND user_pass = '0'
```

Comment: That would work fine however I don't just want to fix the problem as that is simple enough, I want to understand why 0 and 0 return all rows when another int such as 1 doesnt...:S

Comment: @Joe ahh okay, the probably this might shed some light : http://www.cubrid.org/cubrid_implicit_type_conversion .. there is a mysql section with something similar being tested.

Comment: @Joe another useful link : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10771/type-safety-in-where-clauses

Comment: That's great thanks. So if that is the case, I don't understand how an integer of 0 gets converted in a way that then lists all rows however entering 1 and 1 (also integers) doesn't achieve the same effect. Just doesn't seem right lol